wrong keyboard is shown for compose TextField when app comes from background
I am migrating my application from Android to Jetpack Compose and for now i am using ComposeView inside fragments. Inside Login Fragment there is a OutlinedTextField which must accept Phone number only. When app launches for first time when TextField gains focus correct keyboard is shown but when app goes to background and comes to foreground again,, normal keyboard is opened upon clicking TextField.
I have implemented TextField like below:
OutlinedTextField(
    value = phoneNumber.value,
    onValueChange = onValueChange,
    textStyle = textStyle18Normal.copy(
        textDirection = TextDirection.Ltr
    ),
    label = {
        Text(
            text = hintText,
        )
    },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Phone,
    ),
    isError = isError.value,
    supportingText = {
        if (isError.value) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .testTag("inputError"),
                text = errorMessage,
            )
        }
    },
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
    colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
        focusedBorderColor = LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.primary,
        unfocusedBorderColor = LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.neutral40,
        errorBorderColor = LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.semanticError,
        errorLabelColor = LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.semanticError,
        errorLeadingIconColor = LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.semanticError,
        errorCursorColor = LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.semanticError,
        errorSupportingTextColor = LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.semanticError,
        unfocusedLabelColor = LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.neutral60,
    ),
    modifier = modifier
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        .onFocusChanged {
            if (it.isFocused) {
                keyboardController?.show()
            }
        }
)

As you can see i have set keyboardType = KeyboardType.Phone in keyboardOptions.
I also tried putting keyboard type inside remember block but result is same.
I also have to mention that using keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number will not fix the problem and has same behavior.
The left screenshot displays the expected behavior (when the app is opened), the right screenshot shows how it is when the app comes back to the foreground:
 

Can you post the code inside your ComposeView as well?

This is a bug i experienced in a ComposeView inside fragment as well.
I solved this by using DisposableEffect and setting an OpenKeyboardEvent inside ViewModel onPause if keyboard is open before user clicks home button and if that event is not null onResume open keyboard again. This way you make sure that correct keyboard is opened when app is on screen.
@Composable
fun MyComposable(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    val focusRequester = remember {
        FocusRequester()
    }
    
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { source, event ->
            when (event) {
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> {
                    if (viewModel.openKeyboardEvent != null) {
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                        viewModel.openKeyboardEvent = null
                    }
                }

                Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> {
                    // A condition for keyboard to be open
                    if (true){
                        keyboardController?.hide()
                        viewModel.openKeyboardEvent = OpenKeyboardEvent()
                    }
 
                }

                else -> Unit
            }
        }

        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
    
    // Rest of your Composable
}

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var openKeyboardEvent by mutableStateOf<OpenKeyboardEvent?>(
        value = null
    )
}

class OpenKeyboardEvent

If keyboard is supposed to be open all the time you can do it as
@Composable
fun MyComposable() {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    val focusRequester = remember {
        FocusRequester()
    }
    
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { source, event ->
            when (event) {
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> {
                    focusRequester.requestFocus()
                }

                Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> {
                    keyboardController?.hide()
                }

                else -> Unit
            }
        }

        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
    
    // Rest of your Composable
}


hi. I tried your solution but unfortunately it did not work.
